# Error "Cannot utime: Operation not supported" when restoring a tar archive on an android device

Tags: android, tar

I replaced the MicroSD card in my mobile (Samsung Galaxy S4 Mini running CyanogenMod 11 with encryption) with a bigger one.
Before I pulled the old one out I backed up its content into a tar file:

`/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A001%2C016%5D/SD card$ tar czvf ~/tmp/sgm4/sdcard.tar.gz *`

Then replaced the card, formatted the new one and tried to restore my files:

`/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A001%2C017%5D/SD card$ tar xzvf ~/tmp/sgm4/sdcard.tar.gz`

The files got restored but for each one I got an error message like:

```
00001.vcf
tar: 00001.vcf: Cannot utime: Operation not supported
```

Telling me that `tar` is unable to restore the original timestamp of the files. This is confirmed by `ls -l` - it shows the current date and time.

I normally wouldn't worry about it but there are files under Android/data that belong to applications that might be timestamp sensitive.

Is there any mount option or other magic that will allow setting the files' timestamps on a mounted mtp filesystem?

Is the problem related to me using encryption?

Using lubuntu 15.04.

**Update**

It turned out that the MicroSD card itself has been formatted using vfat filesystem without any encryption. I pulled it out of the phone, plugged it in another computer (Ubuntu 14.04) and was able to unpack another tarball without any errors. The timestamps of the unpacked files have been restored correctly.

It looks like the inability to set the timestamp of a file is something mtp speciffic. Does anyone knows how to overcome that?

Answer (score 9):

You get this error when you do not have proper permissions in the target directory, in this case /tmp , or if you are extracting to an non-linux file system (vfat or ntfs).

Extract or make the archive to a location you own, such as your home directory.

Comment: I am the owner of directory `/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A001%2C017%5D/SD card` (and its parent and grandparent too) so I don't expect this to be a permission issue. I know I can extract the files in my home directory and keep the timestamps but I need the files on the MicroSD card, not in my home directory.

Comment: is the sd card FAT ?

Comment: Honestly I don't know. I have encryption enabled on my phone and I asked it to re-format the card. I didn't have the option to choose a filesystem. CM used a filesystem of its choice, I suspect FAT. I don't have an adapter here to plug the card in a different computer and check what is on it. I can check that in ~ 10 hours and report back. Still FAT filesystems do have a concept of file timestamp and that shouldn't be the source of the problem, right?

Comment: I think you get that message with FAT, I am not sure as I do not use FAT much at all these days.

Comment: There is a lot of information about VFAT having problmes with time stamps - http://skillfulness.blogspot.com/2008/11/working-with-fat32-in-ubuntu-linux.html and http://serverfault.com/questions/54949/how-can-i-use-rsync-with-a-fat-file-system and http://yoonkit.blogspot.com/2007/09/preserving-time-stamps-on-fat32-copies.html

Answer (score 2):

In additional to restoring files from an archive, it also attempts to restore timestamp and permissions. As indicated above, some filesystems (perhaps non-Linux, perhaps network drives), do not support a UNIX client setting the timestamp or setting of UNIX permissions. These can result in the following errors from tar:

- Cannot utime: Operation not permitted
- Cannot change mode to rwxrwxr-x: Operation not permitted

If you want to proceed to extract the files anyway and do not care about the original timestamps or permissions, then, you can use these additional options in tar:

> -m, --touch
> Don't extract file modified time.
>
> -no-overwrite-dir
> Preserve metadata of existing directories.

Consult `man tar` for more info.